# I don't have it /have it with (I have it/with me)

Tags: word-usage

If someone asks someone that if someone has something,  what will be natural:

> I don't have it.
>
> I don't have it with me.

And:

> I have it.
>
> I have it with it.

Socegat do you think?

Comment: I would say "I've got it with me" or "I haven't got it with me". But I think these forms are more popular in British than American English.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have it

This means it is not in your possession (but doesn't necessarily specify whether you have it somewhere else or not at all)

> I don't have it with me

This implies you do have it, but it's not with you *right now*. (e.g. it's at home)

> I have it

It is in your posession (but not specifying if it is with you right now)

> I have it with **me**

I have it in my possession right now (e.g. it's in your pocket)

Other ways to respond to *Do you* questions:

> No / No, I don't / I don't / [other versions including an apology]
>
> Yes / Yes, I do / I do, yes / I do

Other ways to respond to *Have you* questions:

> No / No, I haven't / I haven't / [other versions including apology]
>
> Yes / Yes, I have / I have, yes / I have

(There's probably more than the above)

Comment: So is it natural to use: "I have it with me. " And if someone asks "Where's my pencil? " And the other person replies "It's with you. "

Comment: For example: A teacher asks "Submit your notebooks for marking. " And kids reply: "They are already with you. " Or "You already have them. "

Comment: *You already have it* / *You already have them* (*You have it/them*)

Comment: And why doesn't "with you" sound natural whereas "with me" does?

Comment: And would a native be likely to use: "I have it with me.! "

Answer (score 0):

As a general expression of possession:

> I have it / I don't have it
>
> I've got it / I haven't got it

To express current possession on your person:

> I have it with me / I don't have it with me
>
> I've got it with me / I haven't got it with me.

As a response to "where's my pencil?" it depends on whether the speaker assumes you took it.  The negative answer could either be:

> I don't have it. (as in "I didn't **take** it")

or

> I don't know where it is.